# How to set $SERVER variable value from C# while submitting post to php page

Tags: c#, php, post, webclient

I am trying to submit a post request to a php webpage from C#. php query looks like this:

```
    $result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO SomeTable (ID, NAME, PERIOD, INFO, REQUESTED_BY, 
DATE) " ." values (" . $id . ", '" . $_POST['Name'] . "', '" . $_POST['Period'] ."', '" . 
$_POST['Info'] . "', '" . $_SERVER['HTTP_MYCOMPANY_EMAIL'] . "', '".date( 'Y-m-d 
H:i:s')."')");
```

As you can see one of the variable is `$_SERVER['HTTP_MYCOMPANY_EMAIL']` which i want to pass. I cannot impersonate the identity as this code will be executed from the workflow.

This is my C# code looks like:

```
        WebClient objWebClient = new WebClient();
        NameValueCollection objNameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();
        objNameValueCollection.Add("Name", "test123");
        objNameValueCollection.Add("Period", "30 Days");
        objNameValueCollection.Add("Info", "someinfo");
        objNameValueCollection.Add("HTTP_MYCOMPANY_EMAIL", "fname_lname");

        objWebClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        try
        {
            byte[] bytes = objWebClient.UploadValues("https://www.someweb.com/phpPage.php", "POST", objNameValueCollection);
            Console.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes));
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
```

I am able to set the values of `$POST` variable but not the `$SERVER` variable. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

```
objWebClient.Headers.Add("Company-Name", value);
```

Comment: forgot to mention in the post that i tried adding it as header as well but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER is a superglobal array which returns information about the operating environment. You cannot change its values dynamically. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?